# c# HTML web scriping how to handle link click to download files

Tags: c#, browser, web-scraping

In C# windows app, I am using WebBrowser Control and loading a page. I am able to push the required input details into the dropdowns and also hitting a button. It shows me a list of records with links to download files. I want to click and save the document in my c# windows app. How can i do that?

http://www.ceoandhra.nic.in/ceonew/home.aspx

In this site, Click on PDF Electrol Rolls.

Please help me out.....

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't simply downloading the file directly instead of trying to automate the process through the WebBrowser control?

Comment: Yes this is a sample that i am working on. There is a similar case with my project task in office. Link has a dynamically generated URl in postback. So The document URL is not available hardcoded.

Comment: I saw the link in browser source code.                               <a id="GridView1_ctl02_lnkEnglish" href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1$ctl02$lnkEnglish','')">View</a>                                                                           Its not having a URL of the file, its posting back and getting file.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `web-client` if you want to save the file. The URL should a file

```
 string extension = Path.GetExtension(url.ToString());
            List<string> imageFormats = new List<string>() { ".bmp",".dib",".jpg",".jpeg",".jpe",".jfif",".gif",".tif","tiff",".png",".ico"};
            List<string> mswordFormats = new List<string>() { ".doc", ".docx" };
            if (imageFormats.Contains(extension) || mswordFormats.Contains(extension) || extension.Equals(".pdf"))
            {
                string fileName = "download"+ extension;
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.                                            Can I know where the WebClient will store the file ?                       Can we set the path where to save the file ?

Comment: it will store the file from where is application is launched. If you are running it from VS then it will be stored in debug folder of the project.

Comment: This is the control in the webpage seen through page source. <a id="GridView1_ctl02_lnkEnglish" href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1$ctl02$lnkEnglish','')">View</a> THe file url is comming from postback and opening in a new window in browser.